An efficient description of simplicial sets as colimits of standard simplices?
In general, any presheaf $X$ is a colimit of representables indexed by $\int X$. In this proposition from Kerodon, Lurie refines this as follows: if the simplicial set $S$ has dimension $\leq k$ then the canonical map
$$f:\varinjlim _{ ([n], \sigma ) \in \operatorname{{\bf \Delta }}_{S, \leq k} } \Delta ^ n \rightarrow S$$
is an isomorphism. (Here $\operatorname{{\bf \Delta }}_{S, \leq k}$ is full subcategory of elements of $S$ generated by those objects $([n],x)$ with $n \leq k$).
However, this doesn't work for any simplicial set, and the diagram is still bigger than it needs to be. (Say, we measure size using the cardinality of the diagram).
Can we improve on this? E.g., given a simplicial set $S$ can we construct a (not necessarily full) subcategory $D$ of $\int S$ of minimal size such that $\varinjlim _{ ([n], \sigma ) \in D} \Delta ^ n \cong S$?
This would be useful for computing with actual simplices, e.g. $\partial \Delta^n$, $\Lambda^n_j$, etc; and may significantly simplify some proofs in Kerodon.

What I tried:
For the following, by a face of $x$ I mean a simplex $x[f]$ where $f$ is injective.
On one hand, clearly $D$ must contain at least all maximal non-degenerate simplices, i.e. those not that are not a face of another non-degenerate simplex. Looking carefully through Lurie's proof, I think adding all the faces (and face maps) of the these non-degenerate simplices to $D$ is sufficient so that the colimit over $D$ is $S$. My conjecture is that pruning out those faces $y[f]$ of the diagram that "don't add data" (i.e., if $y[f]=z[g]$ for $y$ and $z$ non-degenerate, then they are a face of a simplex $w$) would give the desired $D$. But I haven't been able to show neither that the colimit over this diagram is still $S$ (as Lurie's approach doesn't work anymore), nor that $D$ is of minimal size.

It's not true that $D$ always needs to contain all non-degenerate simplices. The trivial example is $\Delta^n$, in which case you can take $D$ to be a singleton. More interestingly, for $\partial\Delta^n$ and $\Lambda_j^n$, it suffices to take $D$ to consist of the non-degenerate simplices in dimensions $n$ and $n-1$ only (the corresponding colimit formulas are also somewhere in Kerodon). I don't know if there's a more general pattern.

@Thorgott You're right! I think the correct statement is that $D$ should at least have all maximal non-degenerate simplices, where maximal mean it's not a face of another non-degenerate simplex. Also, I'm precisely trying to find that more general pattern you mentioned, and I think my conjecture does cover those cases.

Hmm, if we take the wedge sum $\Delta^2\vee\Delta^1$, it's maximal non-degenerate simplices are precisely $\Delta^2$ and $\Delta^1$, so if you take those and all their faces and face maps, you end up with a diagram whose colimit is just $\Delta^2\sqcup\Delta^1$, cause the inclusion of the wedge point into the first factor is not a face, but a face of a face.

@Thorgott Yes, I'm using the word face for the transitive closure of the usual meaning of "face". See the first line after "What I tried".
